# Chrome hangs on window.print() but not Ctrl+P

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

Using Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79 m

We provide users with a way of printing the current page from a Javascript menu via:
`javascript:window.print();`

This works great in IE and FF, but on Chrome, the page hangs for a good 30 seconds before the Print Preview pops up. Interestingly, Ctrl+P or printing from the Chrome menu works instantly (so it's not printing in general, just bringing up the print preview using Javascript).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A link would be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not publicly accessible.  I tried recreating it on jsFiddle but of course it works for the trivial case.  I'll see if I can make one that reproduces the error... thanks

Comment: If it is in the event of a button: it is unnecessary to call JS. Using something like `onclick="window.print()"` should work fine.

Comment: It happens to be the href of a link, but moving it to an onclick handler and using "#" as the href does not change the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had a 30 second timeout for an unrelated feature of the website that was blocking the print Javascript from being executed. FF and IE had no problems running both but apparently Chrome's threading logic prevented it from launching until the other 30 second timeout.

Not completely resolved but this was a red herring... thanks for the help